# How to randomly assign treatment group in python?

Tags: python, pandas

In my research, I employ regression-based difference-in-difference specification. And to conduct a placebo test, I tried to randomly assign the placebo treated entry year to all treatment groups based on a uniform distribution. For example, my original data looks like this

```
treatment_group_dummy treated_year group_number
 1                     1996            1
 1                     2005            3
 1                     2001            5
 1                     2006            5
 1                     2007            5
 1                     2002            5
```

and I want to randomly assign treated years to all treatment groups based on a uniform distribution from 1996 ~ 2007. For example,

```
treatment_group_dummy treated_year group_number
 1                     2007            1
 1                     1996            3
 1                     2004            5
 1                     2005            5
 1                     2001            5
 1                     2006            5
```

Here is my preliminary code, but I think it does not work at all...

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

random.seed(0)
numGroups=5
numYears=1996 ~ 2007

data = list(it.product(range(numGroups),range(numMembers)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['group','years'])
```

Does anyone give some though about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any initialization of numMembers in your code. So I am not sure about the size of the list you want. But following is a possible implementation

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# set a random seed
np.random.seed(2021)
numGroups = 5

# number of rows in the dataset
size = 10
data = {
    'group': np.random.randint(1, numGroups+1, size),
    'years': np.random.randint(1996, 2008, size)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Edit 1:** Based on the additional explanation from author, when we want to randomize treated_year only

```
df['treated_year'] = np.random.randint(1996, 2008, df.shape[0])
```

Comment: that's right. i have added the modification.

Comment: Thanks Hairul, 
My initial number of group is 194.
Also, What is np.random.seed(2021) means? and what size = 10 means?

Comment: Also, by using your code, I found that there is duplicated group. Is there any way that generate randomize dataset without duplicated group?

Comment: It isn't much clear from the code you shared. but if you already have a df and only want to add randomized treated year to it you can try the following 
``` df['treated_year'] = np.random.randint(1996, 2008, df.shape[0])```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one quick question. Is this code randomly assign year based on uniform distribution?

Comment: yes, this follows uniform distribution . Documentation is here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html